# Is it possible to set the length of a captions max width in the html?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a task and have used a Jquery plugin to create a lightbox photo gallery.  The captions are only allowed to be 600px in length and I am wondering if I can do this in the html, and will it work with the plugin?  The caption comes from the alt="" the plug in I have used is photobox master.  https://github.com/yairEO/photobox

I have tried putting in `style="width: 600px;"`
but may not be placing it correctly.  Any advice / guidance is much appreciated. Thank you.

a html sample is below

```
<li data-keywords="sand dunes beach">
  <a href="Photos/08.jpg">
    <img src="Photos/Thumbnails/08.jpg" alt="Sand Dunes on the beach, could be anywhere in the world, however it is one of my favourite places.  I really enjoyed staying at this location and would recommend it to anyone." title="Sand Dunes" class="photo">
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the style to photobox' `pbCaptionText` class:

```
.pbCaptionText {
  width: 600px;
  /* or alternatively */
  max-width: 600px;
}
```